# How to type special characters used in $\LaTeX$?

Tags: formatting, latex, named-characters

While using $\LaTeX$, there are two characters, \Re and \Im, that represent the real and imaginary parts of a complex number. These look like this:

[image]

How can I type these two characters in Mathematica?

---

Besides, `Style["R I", 20, FontFamily -> "Euclid Fraktur"]` look likes this in my PC:

[image]

I am using Mathematica 12 on Windows 10.

Comment: Press Ctrl-4; and type \Re or  \Re(x) and press Enter to return to the cell.

Comment: You have to install the font or it will revert to a closely matching font. I think this is what is happening. Please get the font [here](http://legionfonts.com/fonts/euclid-fraktur) and then update your post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just take a look at the fonts that you have installed, as `"Euklid Fraktur"` is not available for everyone.

```
Dataset @* Association @@ ({# -> Style["R, I", FontFamily -> #]} & /@ $FontFamilies)
```

[image: Dataset]

To my eyes this is close enough:

```
Style[ "R, I", FontFamily -> "Parchment" ]
```

[image: Re and Im]

But only, if it  is not too big. ;-)

```
Style["R, I", FontFamily -> "Parchment", FontSize -> 48]
```

[image: Large Version]

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this is an answer or what particular use you have in mind, but a font that resembles such $\LaTeX$ typography closely is the "Euclid Fraktur". Not sure if there are better matches in the  "Math Fraktur" family of fonts.

[image]

Consider the [MaTeX](https://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/9355/) package for publication quality work.

---

**EDIT**

I am using Mathematica v12.2.0 on Win7-x64.

For the sake of comparison and entering Gothic versions built into Mathematica (that can be used as symbols inside cells). This is what typing into the LaTeX input box with Ctrl-4 gives you.

[image]

Comment: I believe this is dependent on fonts installed in your system, it shows up as plain R to me on my Mac.

Comment: Strange....`Style["R I", 20, FontFamily -> "Euclid Fraktur"]` looks different in my  computer....

Comment: @gwr Please see if you can get the font [here](http://legionfonts.com/fonts/euclid-fraktur) and if it installs.

Comment: +1 Thanks, that works out nicely. I would add the link to you answer to make it self-contained.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the closest are `\[GothicCapitalR]` and `\[GothicCapitalI]` which can be also typed as <kbd>Esc</kbd>goR<kbd>Esc</kbd> and <kbd>Esc</kbd>goI<kbd>Esc</kbd>. The `TeXForm`s of these are $\mathfrak{R}$ and $\mathfrak{I}$.

Comment: Emmm...how to get the TeXForms in Mathematica?

Comment: `TeXForm[\[GothicCapitalR]]` for instance. The result is a string usable on TeX documents, and thus not really useful *inside* Mathematica, but if you want to export equations to papers (or just here) etc., it can be useful.